# разный подсчет количества символов в строке javascript и php

Tags: php, javascript, strlen

Привет.

```
echo strlen(urldecode('eUU%7B%C2%81%C2%80%7DXNu%40'));
```

выдаёт 13

```
alert(decodeURIComponent('eUU%7B%C2%81%C2%80%7DXNu%40').length);
```

выдаёт 11

Почему так? и как надо изменить php код, чтобы он считал так же как и js?

Comment: а если заместо strlen юзать `mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8')` ?

Comment: Работает! Возникла новая проблемка: `echo ord(mb_substr($str, 4, 1, 'UTF-8'));` возвращает 194, а `alert(str.charCodeAt(4));` выдаёт 129. Как можно помочь php? P.S. нашёл решение проблемы тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333098/utf-8-safe-equivelant-of-ord-or-charcodeat-in-php

Comment: @thetur оформите, пожалуйста, полный ответ на свой вопрос. Всё таки, он теперь будет в поиске и нашедшему требуется ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае надо использовать функцию `mb_strlen`
А именно

`mb_strlen(urldecode('eUU%7B%C2%81%C2%80%7DXNu%40'), 'UTF-8')`

Возвращает 11.

Насчет 2-й проблемы:
можно использовать следующую php функцию для получения кода символа:

```
function utf8_char_code_at($str, $index)
{
    $char = mb_substr($str, $index, 1, 'UTF-8');

    if (mb_check_encoding($char, 'UTF-8')) {
        $ret = mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UTF-32BE', 'UTF-8');
        return hexdec(bin2hex($ret));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Код

```
utf8_char_code_at(urldecode('eUU%7B%C2%81%C2%80%7DXNu%40'), 4);
```

возвратит 129